# Unsure how to implement for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Hello I am having trouble implementing this function

Function:
Decompress the String s. Character in the string is preceded by a number. The number tells you how many times to repeat the letter. return a new string.
"3d1v0m" becomes "dddv"

I realize my code is incorrect thus far. I am unsure on how to fix it.

My code thus far is :
int start = 0;

```
    for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++){
         if (s.isDigit(charAt(s.indexOf(j)) == true){
             Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.index(j))
```

Comment: I suspect you are omitting some of the conditions. For example, what is the longest run of characters?  Is it 0 thru 9 digits, or is 15x a valid representation of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?  Would digits also be encoded?  How would you represent "I am 57"?  And finally, look at converting the entire string into an array so that you can index it directly without having to use indexOf.

Comment: This is not a nested for loop.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the integer you're parsing. Your code is not complete or compilable. Finally, `if (someBoolean == true)` should just be written as `if (someBoolean)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input is in correct format, the following can be a simple code using for loop. Of course this is not a stylish code and you may write more concise and functional style code using [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) or [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2) {
   final int n = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      builder.append(s.charAt(i + 1));
   }
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: What if there are double digit numbers?

Comment: For example this code for this input: 351v0m returns 555v

Comment: Thanks for the nice article. I improved the code using StringBuilder. Does using StringBuilder in this way reduces extra scanning by caching a (kinda) pointer to the end of the String?

Comment: I check AbstractStringBuilder source code and it is linear according to input string and not the source string. So it is fine. Although `+` is translated to `StringBuilder.append` but in `for` loop it does not so using StringBuilder is preferred.

Comment: Correct, a loop is an ideal place to use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution you may like to use that uses `Regex`:

```
    String query = "3d1v0m";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    String[] digitsA = query.split("\\D+");
    String[] letterA = query.split("[0-9]+");

    for (int arrIndex = 0; arrIndex < digitsA.length; arrIndex++)
    {

        for (int count = 0; count < Integer.parseInt(digitsA[arrIndex]); count++)
        {
            result.append(letterA[arrIndex + 1]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
dddv
```

This solution is scalable to support more than 1 digit numbers and more than 1 letter patterns.

i.e.

**Input**

```
3vs1a10m
```

**Output**

```
vsvsvsammmmmmmmmm
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Nami's answer is terse and good. I'm still adding my solution for variety, built as a static method, which does not use a nested For loop, instead, it uses a While loop. And, it requires that the input string has even number of characters and every odd positioned character in the compressed string is a number.

```
public static String decompress_string(String compressed_string)
{
    String decompressed_string = "";

    for(int i=0; i<compressed_string.length(); i = i+2) //Skip by 2 characters in the compressed string
    {
        if(compressed_string.substring(i, i+1).matches("\\d")) //Check for a number at odd positions
        {
            int reps = Integer.parseInt(compressed_string.substring(i, i+1));   //Take the first number
            String character = compressed_string.substring(i+1, i+2);   //Take the next character in sequence

            int count = 1;
            while(count<=reps)//check if at least one repetition is required
            {
                decompressed_string = decompressed_string + character; //append the character to end of string
                count++;
            };
        }
        else
        {
            //In case the first character of the code pair is not a number
            //Or when the string has uneven number of characters
            return("Incorrect compressed string!!"); 
        }
    }

    return decompressed_string; 
}
```